# why it will show AttributeError: module 'self' has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to fill the credit card in check out, but I can not find that

````py
self.driver.switch_to.frame()
self.driver.switch_to.frame("number7fe57559-0283-43ef-90c4-484c5c17c4f1").click```

it show 
```File "C:\Users\harry\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    self.driver.switch_to.frame()
AttributeError: module 'self' has no attribute 'driver'```
https://www.goopi.co/
````

Comment: You need to show more of your code. It is weird that the error is "module 'self' has no attribute..." as that implies you have an `import self` somewhere.  `self` is normally the name of the first argument in methods on classes, which refers to the instance of the class. So it looks like you have copy & pasted some code out of a method and into the top-level of your main.py?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self only inside of a python class. Try without it.